# Is there a rspec equivalent to mockito ArgumentCaptor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mockito

I have a java project that uses ArgumentCaptor in order to assert the calls to a specific mock object (stub). Is there an equivalent Rails Rspec ArgumentCaptor?
I want to be able to mock an ActiveRecord model and compare assert the arguments passed to a save call.

Update 1

Here is an example of a Java code that uses the ArgumentCaptor. Notice the ability to decorate the mock in order to collect all the objects that are passed to the method you are testing then assert on them.

```
 @Test
public void should_import_all_tax_treatment_domain_data() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    this.mockInputStream("DOMAIN-treatment.json");

    // Act
    this.importService.runImport("DOMAIN-treatment.json");

    // Assert
    ArgumentCaptor<TaxTreatment> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(TaxTreatment.class);

    verify(this.taxTreatmentRepositoryMock, times(9)).findByCode(anyString());
    verify(this.taxTreatmentRepositoryMock, times(9)).save(argument.capture());

    assertEquals("Withhold All", argument.getAllValues().get(0).getName());
    assertEquals("Withhold", argument.getAllValues().get(1).getName());
    assertEquals("Pay Cash", argument.getAllValues().get(2).getName());
    assertEquals("None", argument.getAllValues().get(3).getName());
    assertEquals("Sell All", argument.getAllValues().get(4).getName());
    assertEquals("Sell for Taxes", argument.getAllValues().get(5).getName());
    assertEquals("Swap", argument.getAllValues().get(6).getName());
    assertEquals("Debit Rtl Acct", argument.getAllValues().get(7).getName());
    assertEquals("Payroll Deduction", argument.getAllValues().get(8).getName());

}
```

Comment: Yes, they're called... wait for it... Mocks. You might find [this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=rspec+mock) helpful.

Comment: @jvillian I use mocks extensively. The question was not about mock but a specific technique that allows you to collect a list of objects that are used as params on the calls of your stub. I use this in Java since it is present on mockito and it is called ArgumentCaptor. I was looking for something similar or equivalent in Rails. I apologize if my question was not clear enough

Comment: Now it's my turn to apologize. I'm not sure I understand what you're after. You're wanting to test whether the arguments passed to an object meet some set of criteria? (Since I'm unfamiliar with ArgumentCaptor, it is difficult to use it as a reference point.)

Answer (score 1):

RSpec's support for mocks allows using blocks, which provide the possibility "capture" the parameter as follows

```
expect(a_mock).to receive(:save) {|arg| expect(arg.name).to eq "name"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a first attempt at implementing Mockito in RSpec:
[rspec-fire](https://github.com/xaviershay/rspec-fire)

RSpec3 now has support for Mocks:
[rspec3-mocks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double)

Sandi Metz talk on Mocks is good:
[TDD magic tricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M)

And this talk on Mocks in Ruby is useful:
[Why you don't know mocks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9FOchgTtLM)

Comment: An answer is a direct response that sincerely attempts to provide the information/analysis requested by the question. Hence, i need you to understand link is not an actual answer.